# Loop through array with delay

Tags: javascript, loops, delay, settimeout

I have an array with 4 items inside it. I want to loop though the array but during each loop i want to delay it for 5 seconds and do something such as an animation or playing sound:

The array is called donations:

```
for(counter = 1; counter < 4; counter++){

    setTimeout(
        console.log(donations[counter])
        //play_sound(child_node);
    , 1000);

}
```

The problem at the moment is instead of printing to the console every 1 second, it is doing all the prints at once. Isnt setTimeout supposed to introduce a delay.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not blocking.

Comment: use `setInterval` instead.

Comment: Just use `setTimeout` with a loop counter instead. Avoid `setInterval`. You don't need the for loop at all. Put that logic inside your code that you're looping using `setTimeout`. Make the `setTimeout` call conditional based on your loop conditions. Simple :)